# PHP's ob_flush() causing error

Tags: php, buffering, ob-start

When I call PHP's `ob_flush()` function on my localhost (via MAMP) I get the following error:

> Notice: ob_flush() [ref.outcontrol]:
>   failed to flush buffer. No buffer to
>   flush.

The only solution I can find is to prefix it with `@`, but this doesn't seem like a real solution to me.  What's causing the problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error message would seem to imply that you're not actually using output buffering when you call `ob_flush()`. Have you called `ob_start()` previous to invoking `ob_flush()`?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use `ob_flush` you must first call `ob_start()` - desirably at the top of your page.

Not sure if it fits your needs but you might want to also try the plain old `flush()`, just guessing.